# Return to SharePoint Library when closing InfoPath form without Prompt

Tags: document-library, infopath

We have an InfoPath (2010) form that works, except the final rule `Close this Form: No Prompt` leaves a new form open, rather than returning to the SharePoint form/document library ...

Ideally after the user has clicked **Yes** on the confirmation view, and the data has been submitted, the form as has been saved, then the user should return to the library to view the new document?

This is our only issue, everything else works fine - the saved document is in the library, but in order to get to it, the user has to click `Close` on the ribbon

here are some pictures of the issue:

**1 - showing the rule in the designer:**

[image]

**2 - this is where the user should end up:**

[image]

**3 - Unfortunately that final rule leaves a new document open:**

[image]

So, how can we have it close the form and return to the document library as in Image 2?

Comment: remove switch to view action which ran before close this form action.

Comment: Add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove switch to view action which runs before close this form action.